# Why does the OR statement evaluate only one even if both are true?

Tags: c, conditional-statements, boolean-logic

Consider the following C code, according to what I have learnt the OR statement should evaluate both the printf. But in actual output I see only "XX". Why is this happening?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a;
    a = (printf("XX")||printf("YY"));
    printf("%d\n",a);
    a = (printf("XX")&&printf("YY"));
    printf("%d\n",a);
}
```

Output -

XX1 
XXYY1

Comment: that is what is called short circuit evaluation, if the first operand is true, the whole operation is true too, so there is no need to evaluate the second operand

Comment: @EduardoPascualAseff Got it! What should I do now? Delete the question?

Comment: @Agile_Eagle do what you want

Answer (score 2):

OR operator output is true even if one condition is true. And in this case first `printf` statement returns true. So there is no need to evaluate the second operand of OR operator.

Answer (score 2):

`||` operator evaluates to true if any of the operands is true. So if first operand evaluates to `true` it doesn't check the second. It only checks second operand if first operand was false.

`&&` operator evaluates to true only when both the operands are `true`. It would check the second operand iff the first one is not `false`.

As stated in the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

> Upon successful return, these functions return the number of characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to strings).
>   The functions snprintf() and vsnprintf() do not write more than size bytes (including the terminating null byte ('\0')). If the output was truncated due to this limit then the return value is the number of characters (excluding the terminating null byte) which would have been written to the final string if enough space had been available. Thus, a return value of size or more means that the output was truncated. (See also below under NOTES.)

Say you have a code like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d", printf(""));
    return 0;
}
```

This would print `0` just as explained in the manpage.

If your statement is:

```
printf("") && printf("XX");
```

It won't print anything because first operand evaluated to `0`.

Whereas,

```
printf("") || printf("YY");
```

Would print `YY`.

In your case,

```
a = (printf("XX")||printf("YY"));
```

would evaluate `printf("YY")` only when the first operand failed to print anything.

```
a = (printf("XX")&&printf("YY"));
```

Would print `XXYY` when both `printf` were successful.

Answer (score 1):

Say you're trying to answer this question "Is it raining or is it after 7 PM?". Once you see that it's raining, you know the answer is "yes". You have no need to check if it's after 7 PM or not.

```
a = (printf("XX")||printf("YY"));
```

You asked it an "OR" question. Once it evaluates the first `printf`, it knows that the answer to your question is yes, so it has no need to evaluate the second part.

Answer (score 1):

The `||` or OR operator doesn't evaluate its right part if the left part has been determined to be true. Because it does not need to: `TRUE || something` is "always" true. Even if a potential crash hides on the right. The left part is always checked first.

The return value of printf is not "false" in case of error: it return -1. The "false" value is 0, which would occur if you are trying to print an empty format string, or put a '\0' at the beginning of it. Any value that is not 0 is evaluated as "true" in the general case.